# Qt: Draw text in vertical direction with QPainter?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter

How to use QPainter.drawText() API to display text in vertical direction?

The meaning of **vertical direction** is:

```
A
B
C
```

**not** like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to insert endline (`\n`) between each character as shown below:

```
QPainter painter(this);
QString str = "ABCDEFG";
for (int i = 1; i < str.size(); i+=2)
    str.insert(i, '\n');
painter.drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter ,str);
```

Output:

[image]